# How to have two different modals on a same controller on a same page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-directive

I need to have two modal windows on my page, inside of each window is a form with some field, but i dont know how to put all that in a same controller. Here is a plunker link to my code

```
<html>http://plnkr.co/edit/pudTGMcTAiNNJxHjYNut?p=preview</html>
```

It works ok but i dont know how to merge that two controllers into one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at your plunker code, it was pretty easy to combine the `AddControllerGroup` into `AddController`. The only thing stopping it was that you called your method `open` in both controllers.

The updated `AddController` looks like this:

```
sitesApp.controller('AddController', function ($scope, $modal) {
    $scope.openAddSite = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'addSites.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
        });
    };

    $scope.sites = [
        {
            url:'',
            color:'',
            groups: []
        },
        {
            url:'',
            color:'',
            groups: []
        },
        {
            url:'',
            color:'',
            groups: []
        }
    ];

    $scope.openAddGroup = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'addGroups.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
        });
    };

    $scope.groups = [
        {
            name:'',
            color:'',
            sites: []
        },
        {
            name:'',
            color:'',
            sites: []
        },
        {
            name:'',
            color:'',
            sites: []
        }
    ];
});
```

Then I just changed your two buttons to call `openAddSite()` and `openAddGroup()` and it all worked.

You still need to wire up some code to handle the results from the modal, but this should get you started.

Comment: Just for future references, added working http://plnkr.co/edit/GVhngWpytxNXySF55g1R?p=preview